# Spring Hateoas debugging uriTemplate must not be null

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, debugging, spring-hateoas

I am debugging a method which creates a hateoas link. The method is as follows:

```
    public Link getPlansLink(RequestParam requestParam, String linkName){
        ResponseEntity<Plans> methodLinkPlans = ControllerLinkBuilder.methodOn(Plans.class)
            .getPlans(requestParam.getID());
        Link plansLink = ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(methodLinkPlans).withRel(linkName).withType(GET);
        return plansLink;
    }
```

This works fine when the service is running normally but when I try and debug the method, something strange happens...

If I try and add the breakpoint on the lines where methodLinkPlans or plansLink are set and step over, the plansLink link throws the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: 'uriTemplate' must not be null
at org.springframework.util.Assert.hasText(Assert.java:284) ~[spring-core-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.util.UriTemplate.<init>(UriTemplate.java:64) ~[spring-web-5.1.7.RELEASE.jar:5.1.7.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilderFactory.java:141) ~[spring-hateoas-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at org.springframework.hateoas.mvc.ControllerLinkBuilder.linkTo(ControllerLinkBuilder.java:194) ~[spring-hateoas-0.24.0.RELEASE.jar:na]
at com.example.svc.hateoas.HateoesLinks.getPlansLink(HateoesLinks.java:422) ~[classes/:na]
...
```

But when I add the breakpoint to the "return plansLink;" line, I can step over and its all fine.

What is causing this issue? Is the uriTemplate referred to in ControllerLinkBuilder?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your Spring HATEOAS version (0.24.0) is quite old. Try to use the latest one 1.1.0.RELEASE

Comment: Thanks, I will try that at some point. Although this a little complicated due to a number of environments and other services having dependencies on this one. Why is it that an old dependency may cause this debugging issue?

Comment: I hardly can tell why without a producable example project. Version 0.24 was born in 2017 and it is immature. Even though finally find out it is a BUG, probably nothing we can do. The change from 0.24 to 1.1.0 is quite big. The team changed class name, method name, package structure and a lot internal logic. So probably the BUG doesn't exist in the version 1.1.0.

Comment: Try out the [samples](https://spring.io/projects/spring-hateoas#samples) and read the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-hateoas/docs/1.1.0.RELEASE/reference/html/)